# How Can I Get Printer Status

Tags: php, laravel, zebra-printers

This code is printing fine

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
class PrintBarCodeController extends Controller
{
    public function printBarcode(Request $request)
    {
         try {

            $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("ZDesigner ZD230-203dpi ZPL");
            // Create a new Printer object and assign the connector to it
            $printer = new Printer($connector);

                    $zplCode = "90809283048";
                    $printer->textRaw($zplCode);

                    // Cut the paper
                    $printer->cut();

                    // Close the connection to the printer
                    $printer->close();

            return response()->json(
                ['message' => 'ZPL code printed successfully',
                ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the printing process
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error printing ZPL code: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i check if the printer is Offline or Online?

I do some searching and find out that the mike42 doesn't have a method for that so I use shell_exec
i first try ipconfig and its working but when i try `shell_exec(Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = \"$printerName\"');` it does not echo anything

Comment: Won't an exception be thrown if the printer is offline? If yes, you can catch it. (By the way, why is this question tagged "powershell"?)

Comment: No, when I print, it goes straight to the printing queue even if the printer was offline. (Because I tried to use the shell_exec so I thought I should include "PowerShell")